function returning list with one extra length than it should
I have data that looks like this:
data = [[['INS', 'Y', '18', '021', '28', 'A', '', '', 'AC'],
         ['REF', '0F', '816383217'],
         ['HD', '021', '', 'EPO', 'Copayment Level -1', 'IND']],
        [['INS', 'Y', '18', '024', '07', 'A', '', '', 'TE'],
         ['REF', '0F', '734419065']],
        [['INS', 'Y', '18', '024', '07', 'A', '', '', 'TE'],
         ['REF', '0F', '778954065']]]

I want to loop through it and create a pandas series of the copayment_level which is the number after the dash -.  If that element does not exist in the list of lists then it should append None to the new list.  I created a function to do this but the problem is it returns one extra than it should.
def copay_level():
    l = []
    for i in data:
        for lst in i:
            for x in lst:
                if x.startswith('Copayment Level'):
                    x = x.split('-')
                    l.append(x[1])
        else:
            l.append(None)
    return l

copayment_level = pd.Series(copay_level())
print(copayment_level)

0       1
1    None
2    None
3    None
dtype: object

Cant figure out why its doing this.  Thanks

The else is lined up with a for and not an if, is that what you intended?

yes that way if the sublist doesnt contain the copay element it appends `None

The else: block of a loop is executed whenever the loop ends normally, instead of with break. Since you have no break statements, you'll always append None for each item in data, even if it contains Copayment Level.

where should the break statement go?

Do you ever expect more than one copayment? You could replace the entire inner loop with something like l.append(cop.split('-')[1] if any((cop := x).startswith('Copyament Level') for x in lst else None).

(Maybe even the 2 inner loops; I'm not sure I read that correctly.)

No always just one copayment

You have to avoid adding None if you found Copayment Level in the item. Use a variable to track this.
def copay_level():
    l = []
    for i in data:
        found_copay = False
        for lst in i:
            for x in lst:
                if x.startswith('Copayment Level'):
                    x = x.split('-')
                    l.append(x[1])
                    found_copay = True
        if not found_copay:
            l.append(None)
    return l

You could do this with else: if you only had one level of looping, and used break when you find a Copayment Level. But since that's in a nested loop, else: won't detect a break there.

You need to ensure that you're only appending None when no copayment level is found the an entire sublist of data.
def copay_level():
l = []
for i in data:
    hasCoLev = False;
    for lst in i:
        for x in lst:
            if x.startswith('Copayment Level'):
                x = x.split('-')
                l.append(x[1])
                hasCoLev = True
                break      
        if hasCoLev:
            break
    if not hasCoLev:
        l.append(None)
return l

You can use break statements to exit loops early once you find a copayment level.
